# Populating a table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table in my database like this:

```
IdUser | Name | Surname |
```

And another table with the following strucutre

```
IdPN | IdUser | PhoneNumber
```

The PK of this table is `IdPN`, so each User can have more than one Phone number.

Now I'm getting the data from the first table for pupulating a table in my HTML page. I want something like this:

```
name | Surname| numbers  |
_____|________|__________|
John | Doe    | 21212121 |
     |        | 23424324 |
_____|________|__________|
Frank|Johnson | 23222111 |
     |        | 23747347 |
     |        | 36363636 |
_____|________|__________|
```

So the third colume can have more than one numbers.

The code php that I was using when I had just one number for each user, is the following:

```
<?php
      $connectiondb->set_charset("utf8");
      $query= "SELECT name, surname, phonenumber
      FROM users";
        if ($stmt = $connectiondb->prepare($query)) {
          $stmt->execute();

      $stmt-bind_result($nome,$cognome,$phonenumber);
            while($stmt->fetch()){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$nome.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$cognome.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$phonenumber.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';

}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

How I have to change my code for showing multiple number for each row of the table (user)?

Comment: How could `"SELECT name, surname, phonenumber
      FROM users"` possibly run? I though phonenumber was from a different table than the other 2?

Comment: You need to have a row for each phone number with it's own idPN or you're going to be in a world of hurt using that table. Also I'd suggest adding a 'type' column to distinguish work from cell from home, etc

Comment: @Jordan I was talking about my old code, when the phoenumber was just one for each user, so the second table wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare your recordset before being output to the front end.

```
<?php
$connectiondb->set_charset("utf8");
$query= "SELECT users.IdUser, users.Name, users.Surname, phones.PhoneNumber
         FROM users
         LEFT JOIN phones ON (users.IdUser = phones.IdUser);";
if ($stmt = $connectiondb->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $nome, $cognome, $phonenumber);

    /*
      Recordset will be 
      |1|Jim|Bowen|07235876583
      |1|Jim|Bowen|07734952651
      |2|Jim|Davidson|07275493085
      |2|Jim|Davidson|07197649387
      |2|Jim|Davidson|07030190594       

     */
    $result = array();
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        if(!isset($result[$id]))
        {
            // save any previous person in $result
            if(is_array($temp)) $result[$id] = $temp; 

            // start a fresh person
            $temp = array();

            // first time to come accross this person
            $temp['id'] = $id;
            $temp['name'] = $nome;
            $temp['surname'] = $cognome;
            $temp['phonenumbers'] = array($phonenumber);
        }
        else
        {
            // if we've already come across this person, only store his/her next phonenumber in the array
            $temp['phonenumbers'][] = $phonenumber
        }
    }

    /* the $result array will now look thus
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string 'Jim' (length=3)
          2 => string 'Bowen' (length=5)
          3 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string '07235876583' (length=11)
              1 => string '07734952651' (length=11)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '2' (length=1)
          1 => string 'Jim' (length=3)
          2 => string 'Davidson' (length=8)
          3 => 
            array (size=3)
              0 => string '07275493085' (length=11)
              1 => string '07197649387' (length=11)
              2 => string '07030190594' (length=11)
    */
$stmt->close();
}
```

You can now echo out like this:

```
foreach($result as $row)
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['surname'].'</td><td>'.implode(', ', $row['phonenumber'].'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thank you @Mei. But, are you sure that if(is_array($temp)) make sense?

Comment: I have just modified slightly your code, and now it works. your idea was good. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT PhoneNumber FROM PhoneNumbers WHERE IdUser = $user_id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['PhoneNumber'] . "<br />\n";
}
```

That block of code can be used to display a list of phone numbers for `$user_id` separated by line breaks. Placed inside the `<td>` tag of your phone number area will do the trick, as long as `$user_id` is defined.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `mysql_**` functions, they are deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: this is probably the simplest way to achieve the solution, but probably wouldn't be very fun to style.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL to include the `IdUser` column as follows:

```sql
SELECT users.IdUser, users.Name, users.Surname, phones.PhoneNumber
FROM users
LEFT JOIN phones ON (users.IdUser = phones.IdUser);
```

Then you can use the PHP to sort the phones into structured arrays and go from there:

```php
$aUsers = array();
$aUserPhones = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (!isset($aUsers)) {
        $aUsers['UserId'] = array(
            'nom'       =>  $nom,
            'cognom'    =>  $cognome,
            'phones'    =>  array($phone),
        );
    }
    else {
        $aUsers[$userId]['phones'][] = $phone;
    }

}

foreach ($aUsers as $aUser) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$aUser['nome'].'</td>'
    echo '<td>'.$aUser['cognome'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo implode('<br>', $aUser['phones']);
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: this I thin required a LEFT OUTER JOIN between the users table and the phonenumber table, right?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you needed the SQL help as well. Assuming that the phone numbers are optional, I've updated my answer to include the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: In this case, considering the example in my question, I will have a table with 5 rows, but I want a table with 2 row (one for each user)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an `ID` instead of a `Name`.

Your data will come back like this:

```
name | Surname| numbers  |
_____|________|__________|
John | Doe    | 21212121 |
John | Doe    | 23424324 |
John | Doe    | ######## |
--------------------------
```

**Edit: re-read the question, noticed your table structure**

query will turn into:

```
            SELECT name, surname, phonenumber, phone_ct

            FROM   users as u 

                   join phone_numbers as ph
                      on ph.IdUser = u.IdUser 

                   join phone_numbers as ph
                      on ph.IdUser = u.IdUser 

                   join (select IdUser, 
                                count(IdPN) as phone_ct 
                         from phone_numbers
                         group by IdUser ) as ph_count   
                      on ph_count.IdUser = u.IdUser
```

now data will turn into:

```
name | Surname| numbers  | phone_ct
_____|________|__________|___________
John | Doe    | 21212121 |        3 |
John | Doe    | 23424324 |        3 | 
John | Doe    | ######## |        3 | 
-------------------------------------
```

**edit:  updated code to maybe actually work (lol... sorry)**

code will turn into:

```
<?php
      $connectiondb->set_charset("utf8");
      $query = "
            SELECT name, surname, phonenumber, phone_ct

            FROM   users as u 

                   join phone_numbers as ph
                      on ph.IdUser = u.IdUser 

                   join phone_numbers as ph
                      on ph.IdUser = u.IdUser 

                   join (select IdUser, 
                                count(IdPN) as phone_ct 
                         from phone_numbers
                         group by IdUser ) as ph_count   
                      on ph_count.IdUser = u.IdUser ";

      if ($stmt = $connectiondb->prepare($query)) 
      {
         $stmt->execute();  
         $stmt->bind_result($nome, $cognome, $phonenumber, $phone_ct);

         $row_ct = 0; 

         while($stmt->fetch())
         { 
            $row_ct++ 

            // do every row for every section
            echo '<tr>';

            // first row of this section 
            if ($row_ct==1)                    
            { 
               echo "<td rowspan=$phone_ct>".$nome.'</td>';
               echo "<td rowspan=$phone_ct>".$cognome.'</td>';
            }

            // do every row for every section
            echo '<td>'.$phonenumber.'</td>';    
            echo '</tr>';

            // end of this section 
            if ($row_ct==$phone_ct) {           
              $row_ct = 0; 
            }   
        }

        $stmt->close();

     }  // end if $stmt
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

If you have two tables;

```
IdUser | Name | Surname  
IdPN | IdUser | PhoneNumber
```

What I would do it use the first table as your "primary" table, and the second as a secondary.  IdUser is going to be your PK in your primary, but IdUser in your secondary will be a foreign key to IdUser in the primary table (since these two pieces of information are the same and you really shouldn't be adding objects to the phone number table without a corresponding entry in the primary table.)  You should be able to perform a query off of both tables to present the information you need (like, maybe, a full join).  As an example ;

```
select a.IdUser, a.Name, b.Surname, b.IdPN, b.PhoneNumber from <primary table> as a, <secondary table> as b where a.IdUser=b.IdUser;
```

This is an example, so don't copy and paste it in, but the point is that if the relationship between the two tables is consistent, you should be able to perform a single query to get everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Execute query like

```
SELECT A.name, A.surname,GROUP_CONCAT(phonenumbers) as phone_number
FROM TABLE1 A 
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.iduser = B.iduser
GROUP BY A.iduser
```

From this query you will get phone number comma separated

Example : (1123132132,123123133)

Use explode to split

```
$get_number = explode(" ", $number);
```

Now you will get numbers in an array `$get_number`. Get the count of number by

```
$row_span = count($get_number);
```

Now you will have the row span. Using foreach you can print the numbers in table. 
So Your td will be like

```
<td rowspan="<?php echo $row_span; ?">
```

I hope this will help you. If need any assistance, please let me know